# What could a weakness be for a gaseous species?

Tags: aliens, gas

I am currently working on a space opera setting, and I wanted to include a gaseous species of sapient aliens that hail from a gas-giant reminiscent of Jupiter.

Before I ask my question, I wanted to give a brief description for them. They are very similar to a character from Hellboy called Johann Kraus, in the sense that they are often confined into a specialized containment suit when they interact with other sapient species. In their true form however, they are little more than a floating cloud of gas.

They are biologically immortal, and do not require food, water, sleep, or oxygen to survive, but they are still capable of being killed. The thing is though, I can’t for the life of me figure out how to kill them.

My question is this: How could you kill a being made out of gas in a believable way?

Comment: Maybe use an antimatter gun like Morty used to kill Fart ? Idk how scientifically accurate that would be though given how hard it is to contain antimatter, and its contact with matter results in a large release of gamma radiation.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH if we're being "scientifically accurate", the amount of antimatter to form a "regular" bullet (9 mm parabellum, 8gram), when in contact with matter would explode with about 350 kilotons (~26 "hiroshimas"). so yeah, that would certainly kill the gaseous lifeforms, as well as everything else within a few kilometers.

Comment: what DO they need, life has to consume something, it needs energy and replacement material.  A floating cloud og gas is not coherent so what do they sue to hold themselves together in their own environment.

Comment: well they should have a problem with high gee forces.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

## A big fan.

Your aliens are so astronomically ineffable, the fans will tear them to pieces.  Think of it as a teleporter set to Maximum Dispersion, without the need to lose a few crewmen experimenting with it on the maiden flight.

We know from so many classic video games that any unstoppable combat monster who can take hits from rocket launchers and gargle with molecular acid, curing the damage with a bottle of water from time to time, will *instantly* and *irrevocably* be torn to bloody chunks if he so much as touches the spinning blades of death of a desk or ceiling fan.  Now imagine what something like *this* could do to a being made out of gas.

Comment: A hand-held fire extinguisher might also do the trick.

Comment: As snarky as this answer was, as badly as I wanted to NOT vote for it, it was still the obvious answer. A gas species isn't the least vulnerable race, it's the most. I don't even think it could evolve on a gas giant.

Comment: @Daron - it's true that the extinguisher, adding cold and CO2 to the mix, might do better than a fan.  But in my defense I should say I posted a graphic of a jet engine, thinking that in case the airflow doesn't work we might finish them off with burning kerosene.  DWKraus -  as for snark, well ... I had to stay awake long enough to finish typing the answer, no?

Answer (score 8):

### A: Its parts MUST be interconnected by something, meaning its parts can be taken apart.

You can not actually make anything intelligent out of a true gas because gas is constantly reconfiguring itself.  A memory is formed by creating a network of connections that can be repeated.  If your body is just drifting around formlessly, then it can not create a discrete pattern out of your component parts meaning you can not have memory or intelligence.

Instead, I will suggest your organism is LIKE a gas.  It could be made up a colony of microscopic solid things (cells) that move together kind of like a cloud of plankton. They may not be able to maintain a structure physically, but if you treat them like a wireless network, they could use a system whereby each cell is like a computer with a unique IP address; so, the cells could network by some sort of organic WIFI in leu of physical connections. So, two cells could remain "connected" even over a distance.  This way you can hit it, cut it, blow it around, or whatever you want and none of it will have any meaningful effect on the organism as long as its cells remain within transmission range.

The best way you kill a human is to interrupt the physical interconnectedness of our forms (often in the form of a blade or bullet.), but with these organisms, the target you want to go after is the "wifi" connection.  Depending on how these organism communicate, this could involve something as simple as a radio jamming signal.

### B: If it can think and act in any way, it can be starved

Just because they do not need "food", does not mean they do not get their energy from somewhere.  Thinking and moving around both require that the organism contain some manner of potential energy that it can control and release whenever it needs to perform some action.  Perhaps your organism "eats" the chemicals in its native atmosphere, or maybe it is photosynthetic.  But no matter where it gets its power from, it needs to come from somewhere meaning that as long as you isolate the being for long enough, it will eventually starve.

### C: Life is only fit in the environments it is adapted to

In all likelyhood, the Earth will be just as fatal to these guys as Jupiter is too us.  They evolved under high pressures and low temperatures.  It is unlikely that its physiology is able to survive in the relative vacuum that we call air.  Plus all that oxygen and nitrogen may be very toxic if their bodies are not used to it.  Oxygen is highly reactive with a lot of things after all.

Answer (score 3):

## Change their chemical structure

Once someone understands the beings chemical structure, you can develop methods to alter the chemical structure.

Even Helium atoms can form compounds under great pressure or when their ionized.

## Change their Atomic structure

You can also destroy it by changing the Atomic that make it up.

You destroy them by using the same process of changing lead into gold or Helium into lithium. (An Atomic reaction)

## Overall

- trap it in a centrifuge and increase pressure
- electrocute it
- nuke it

  - microwave (ionize)
  - lasers (the kind that induce fusion)
  - x-rays/Gama rays (ionized, maybe some fission)
  - small tactical nuke

Any one of Dr. Evil's High School science fair project should work.

Answer (score 3):

**Phase change**

Without knowing anything about the biology of these gaseous creatures, I can reasonably guess that making them not-a-gas would be catastrophic for them. You can turn most any gas into a liquid or solid by increasing the pressure or decreasing the temperature. Turning them into a liquid might not be deadly since it's still a fluid that allows for relative movement of molecules, but I can't imagine that a creature evolved to exhibit gaseous biology could still function as a solid.

Turning a solid creature into a liquid or gas is 100% deadly, so I imagine the reverse is true for a gaseous creature.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be killing them per se, but can't you just suck them up with a vacuum cleaner. You could connect it to a container and store them.

Once they are in a container it could be easier to kill them, extreme heat or cold come to mind, or blasting them with lethal doses of ionizing radiation could do the trick. It depends on what they are susceptible to. Alternatively (and this depends on what you want to do with your story) an evil scientist could experiment on them and even use them to power their machines.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## high voltage

basically just shoot them with lightning.
where it hits directly, the gas turns into plasma - that would be the equivalent of burning an organ to a crisp.
additionally, the strong electric field will greatly disturb whatever inner workings keeps them coherent, scrambling not only their physical "bodies", but also their consciousness.

*additional benefit*: lightning rifles. rule of cool applies.

Answer (score 1):

If their home planet is a gas giant like Jupiter, then it would make sense, that they need high atmospheric pressure to survive.
That would also fit to their containment suits.

When humans leave earth, we maintain a pressure in our spaceships that is somewhere close to the pressure we are accustomed to. It is necessary for our survival. We can't survive in very low pressure, as our blood would start to boil, and we can't survive in very high pressure, as we would get crushed.

Just changing from normal pressure to very high pressure or vice versa in a short amount of time can be deadly.

So when your aliens want to leave their planet, they would need to take some of their atmosphere with them, or at least keep themselves pressurized.

Destroying their containment should do the trick. Their molecules would be sucked out of their suits, mixing with molecules from the surrounding air. Whichever force kept them bound together will be broken (especially if you decide for this to be the case) and they would cease to exist.

Now killing them on their home planet would be a different topic, as they would not be dependent on their suits to keep themselves pressurized.

Luckily, explosives change the pressure of their nearby surroundings quite drastically. So while bullets would just pass through them, explosives might be the way to go.

Now maybe you don't like any of these ways, as they are just too normal or you want your story to take time before your heroes find out how to kill them. Then maybe you like this way:

Your aliens are made out of different gaseous molecules. They would have to be either in a very stable state (so they don't react with other molecules in the air around them), or there are just no molecules in the air around them they can interact with.

Bringing in molecules to interact with would turn them in new molecules (like your skin turns into new molecules when it burns and reacts with the oxygen in the surrounding air) or you can bring in a catalyst that helps the molecules of the aliens bind with the molecules of the surrounding air.

Answer (score 0):

Killing; bah.  Banal.  Done, done, done done.

They do not die.  **They diffuse away.**

Under circumstances of reduced cohesion (which are a threat in gaseous environments - thus the suit) the gas comprising these creatures may not be able to aseemble their molecules back into their bodies.  They are too spread out.  They remain sentient, but incapable of affecting their environments or being affected as the cloud that they are grows larger and larger.

They cease to exist as physical organisms.  They observe.  As their molecules spread out more and more, blown on the wind and carried underground by the rain, they observe more and more.  These dispersed entities do not go mad as they become enormous in size because there is so much to observe.

---

Could there be a way to bring one back?  What would it say?

Answer (score 0):

You know they are gaseous, so in order to render them incapable, freeze or liquify them, by drastically lowering the temperature and increasing the pressure.

This presumably does not kill them, so at this point it is best to change their chemical structure, slitting the bonds in their molecules, so they are no longer alive.

How to do this depends on the various properties of your lifeform. It being gaseous, the first step is the same no matter what. This would give you time to try several other tactics to actually kill the lifeform, for example acids, or bases, or maybe high electrical charges, or maybe all three, or something else entirely.

With the being in the frozen state,  scientists could figure out their exact chemical structure with no risk, and then proceed to kill the being, by whichever method is best. This is a foolproof method that works independent of the exact chemical structure of this lifeform.

You *could* just nuke them, but that entails the risk that it might make them more powerful(giving a gaseous immortal being a very large amount of energy without knowing exactly how they work may not be such a good idea).